# pwa - prompt add to home screen dosen't show

Tags: javascript, symfony, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I develop a web application with symfony 4.3, then I add pwa features to it. I test with lighthouse extension in chrome and this is result:

[image]

Now problem is prompt for add icon to home screen dosen't show and I have this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prompt' of undefined

code js:

```
var deferredPrompt ;
var btnAdd = document.getElementById('butInstall') ;

function launchPromptPwa(){
    var deferredPrompt;

    btnAdd = document.getElementById('butInstall') ;

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt',  (e) => {
        console.log('0');

        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        deferredPrompt = e;
        btnAdd.style.display = block;
        showAddToHomeScreen();
    });

    btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('1');
        //btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
        //Show the prompt
        deferredPrompt.prompt();
        // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        deferredPrompt.userChoice
            .then((choiceResult) => {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                    console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
                } else {
                    console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
                }
                deferredPrompt = null;
            });
    });


    window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
        console.log('a2hs installed');
    });

    if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
        console.log('display-mode is standalone');
    }

}
```

I test for the display prompt in chrome.

Comment: Seems like `deferredPrompt` is not set at the time, when you call `deferredPrompt.prompt()`.

Comment: but how to define deferredPrompt when call deferredPrompt.prompt() !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the error you can test first whether the `deferredPrompt` variable is initialised and skip the code logic if undefined:

```
if (deferredPrompt) {

  deferredPrompt.prompt();

 // ... 
}
```

Then, is the `beforeinstallprompt` event triggered? 
If so, you have to proof if the `event` object is defined, as you use it to initialise your variable:

```
deferredPrompt = e;
```

Keep in mind that you need a running `service worker` in order to let the `beforeinstallprompt` event being triggered. And the service worker needs a secure connection (https) or running localhost and served via web server.

You can open Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and access the "Application" tab to verify that a web manifest is correctly set and a service worker is installed.

I wrote some articles about [service workers, caching strategies and PWAs](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) if you are interested in deepening the topic.

---

**UPDATE**
If you want to serve content offline, you have to implement caching strategies for your service worker (eg. Stale while revalidate). Following the link above you can learn about different strategies and how you can implement them.

When you implement caching strategies, all the static assets (like css or js files) or data requests will be intercept by the service worker and if there is a match with the given rules, it will cache them or provide them from the cache. Since the cache is on the client side, those resources are available also offline.

As example, to cache static assets:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(
        [
          '/css/bootstrap.css',
          '/css/main.css',
          '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          '/js/jquery.min.js',
          '/offline.html'
          // Add anything else you need to be cached during the SW install
        ]
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: possible to put all the site visible in offline mode ?

Comment: I have request to server for get data ... how to work this request in offline ??

Comment: You have to configure which routes/endpoints you want to cache. You can also use glob expressions. Then when you app makes a GET Request (or the request for a static asset) if there is a match with one of the configured endpoints, the sw will cache the response, according to which strategy did you choose.

Comment: how to display modal if page X is not availible in mode offline ..for example in mode online I visite page login and home and in mode offline i visite page register and this page is not available it will display error "the page is not accessible" .. instead of display error navigator it will display modal

Comment: You have to design a generic offline page (or something similar, according to your needs) where to redirect all the traffic in case the user opens a page that has not been cached before. This would give you enough flexibility to cover cases like your current one.

Comment: how to add all files js and images and css in cache?